# NoSuchMethodException when trying to create RequestSpecBuilder object

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, rest-assured, serenity-bdd

I'm trying to extend RequestSpecBuilder in Rest Assured and make it into a Singleton so I can front load things like the base uri and pass it around between Scenarios in a Serenity BDD implementation of Cucumber. The basic version (with everything else commented out, is this:

```java
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;

public class CareRequestSpecBuilder extends RequestSpecBuilder {

  private static CareRequestSpecBuilder builder;

  public CareRequestSpecBuilder() {
    super();
  }
}
```

I've tried it without `super()` as well. I've tried creating just a basic junit test in the library that creates the object and I still get the attempt to construct through Reflection and the `NoSuchMethodException`. That one is just a basic

```java
import io.restassured.builder.ResponseSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.specification.ResponseSpecification;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DebugTest {

  @Test
  public void restAssuredTest() {
    ResponseSpecification resp = new ResponseSpecBuilder().expectStatusCode(200).build();
  }
}
```

The exception that comes from it is:

```java
BUG! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.<init>(java.lang.Class,int)
BUG! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.<init>(java.lang.Class,int)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7.<clinit>(Java7.java:44)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:128)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:350)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:645)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.createPlugin(VMPluginFactory.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:37)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:99)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:71)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:621)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseParserRegistrar.<init>(ResponseParserRegistrar.groovy)
    at io.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:346)
    at io.restassured.builder.ResponseSpecBuilder.<init>(ResponseSpecBuilder.java:66)
    at <repo package>.autotest.DebugTest.restAssuredTest(DebugTest.java:11)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:119)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup.<init>(java.lang.Class,int)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3508)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2711)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7.<clinit>(Java7.java:42)
    ... 65 more
```

The version if I let it go to the extend version is longer, but ultimately the same cause and process.

The constructor for RequestSpecBuilder is this:

```java
private final ResponseSpecification spec;

public ResponseSpecBuilder() {
        spec = new ResponseSpecificationImpl(rootPath, null, getResponseParserRegistrar(), restAssuredConfig(), new LogRepository());
    }
```

Comment: Edits were to remove company specific info and to correct the title from ResponseSpecBuilder to RequestSpecBuilder.

Comment: `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle$Lookup` does not have a constructor that takes a a `Class` and `int`. Don't expect internal APIs to be stable.

Comment: Relevant groovy bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9211